# FTPS connection with C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftps

I am looking for some help with creating an ftps connection, not sftp - in c#

I am looking to download a file, and upload a file, using ftps and c#

However all my google searches tells me, to download external libraries and stuff - dosnt C# have something build in to to this?

Any example code very much appriciated:)

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534908/transfer-files-over-ftps-ssl-tls-using-c-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you didn't ask for external libraries, but this one makes it much easier.
Otherwise you have to roll your own etc etc.
I recommend [system.net.ftpclient.](https://netftp.codeplex.com/)

Comment: how to use ftpclient? send file, download etc.?