# SFTP server or FTPS Server?

Tags: c#, .net, ssh

I need to create a C# client with .NET Framework 4.6.2 to connect a server.

My client offers me the possibility to connect to a SFTP server or to a FTPS server, but I don't know which one is the best to connect with.

On this [page](https://www.eldos.com/security/articles/4672.php?page=all), I have found this:

> No built-in SSH/SFTP support in VCL and .NET frameworks

I need to connect to a server to upload and download files. I also need to monitor a directory on the server to know when a file is on that remote directory.

Searching on Internet I'm not sure if the .NET libraries ([SSHNet](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET)) that implements SFTP protocol are good enough to a production environment.

I think SFTP is the best option to use but FTPS could be easier to implement a C# client for it.

Or maybe I can use [libssh2](https://www.libssh2.org/) to implement a C program that do the job to monitor a remote directory, download any new file on it and upload the files that I need to upload.

Any advice?

Comment: What kind of things will you need to do with the server later? Just upload o download a single file, or are you looking at full “FTP client” functionality here? Is bundling an executable an option?

Comment: SFTP and FTPS are different things with different features. The choice between them depends not only of what‘s easily available but of your needs !

Comment: @poke I need to connect to a remote server to upload and download files. I also need to monitor a directory on the server to know when a file is on that remote directory.

Comment: @AFract My client offers me the possibility to connect to a SFTP server or to a FTPS server, but I don't know which are the best to connect with.

Comment: I've posted an answer. I recommend FTPS, but your needs are still not totally clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both protocols are fine for your actual needs (as suggested in your question and comments), if it's only a matter of "what's the easiest to use in .Net", I would simply go for FTPS.

It's very fast to implement, since you'll find all what you need in the framework ("FtpWebRequest" class, or more recently ["WebClient"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx), etc), even on old versions of the framework.

You can find plenty resource about this on the web or on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534908/transfer-files-over-ftps-ssl-tls-using-c-net)

You have mentioned that you need to "monitor" a folder on remote server. Of course there's no problem with FTPS to retrieve the list of all files of a folder, but it will be in "pull" mode, as frequently as you wish. There's no way for the server itself to push you a notification every time a new file has been dropped. So if you need some real-time notifications, it's not optimal.